# iOS not showing Tab Bar and TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos

I created Tab Bar application and created one button at the first view controller. This button has action which open second view controller. Then second view controller is loaded, table bar disappeared.
How can I show table bar on all view controllers?
Describe it in details, please. I just start learning iOS application developing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMgqB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToRVx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4h1h.png)

Comment: What is your code for handling the button?

Comment: I didn't write code. I only created relation between button and second view controller - Present modally, in main.storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a navigation controller in between tab bar controller and first view controller. First view controller should be the root view controller for the navigation controller.

[image]

And Secondly on button event you have to select segue type as below:
This will push the second viewcontroller from the first one and will also have the tab bar at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: And one moment please) If I chose not Show action, I don't see tab bar. For example - Present Modally. Why?

Comment: that is default behavior. when presented modally, by default it is shown as fullscreen and everything in the screen will be only form the presented view controller. For more info you can have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc